# Creating a table from a BigQuery query, with field descriptions

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery DDL to create tables from queries, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.bens_test_table` AS
SELECT "test data" AS my_field
```

When creating tables in this way there are no descriptions on the field in the BigQuery UI:

[image]

I would like to add field and table descriptions when creating a table. I have been reading through the documentation and I can create an empty table with field and table descriptions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.bens_test_table`
(my_field STRING OPTIONS(description="A description."),
my_int INT64 OPTIONS(description="A number field.")
)
OPTIONS(
  description="Hello, this is my test table.", 
  friendly_name="My friendly table"
)
```

However when I try to combine these two to create a table from a query, I get an error when trying to add in the descriptions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.bens_test_table` AS
(SELECT "test data" AS my_field)
OPTIONS(
  description="Hello, this is my test table.", 
  friendly_name="Ben is cool"
)
```

Can this be done using the BigQuery UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of the `OPTIONS` and the `AS` blocks. Check the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_or_replacing_a_table) for more query syntax information.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.bens_test_table`
(my_field STRING OPTIONS(description="A description."),
my_int INT64 OPTIONS(description="A number field.")
)
OPTIONS(
  description="Hello, this is my test table.", 
  friendly_name="Ben is cool"
)
AS (SELECT "test data" AS my_field, 1 AS my_int)
```

Comment: Thank you! How about descriptions for individual fields? Where do you place `OPTIONS()` for these?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include individual field descriptions. Hope it helps!